# Given entire functions $f,p$, find holomorphic $g$ with $g \circ p = f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,p: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be two entire functions, where $p$ is non-constant (so that $\Omega := p(\mathbb{C})$ is open, by the open mapping theorem).

Assume also that the following condition holds:

$$\forall z,w\in \Omega, \quad p(z)=p(w)\implies f(z)=f(w).$$

This means that the function:

$$g:\Omega \to \mathbb{C},\quad g(p(z)):=f(z) $$

is well-defined.

**Question:** is $g$ necessarily holomorphic in $\Omega$?

It's a nice exercise to show that this holds if $p(z)=z^k$ for $k\ge 1$, but I'm not sure if it holds in general.

Here's the strategy I had in mind:

**Step 1:** If $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $p'(z_0)\neq 0$, then $p$ is locally invertible in a neighborhood $V\ni z_0$, and then $g$ is holomorphic in $p(V)$ as $g=f\circ p^{-1}$ there.

Thus, $g$ is holomorphic in $\Omega - p(E)$, where $E := \{p' = 0 \}$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

**Step 2:** Show that $p(E)$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

I don't know how to do this step- I'm not even sure if $p(E)$ is closed (as $p$ is not necessarily a closed map).

If true, this would imply that the points of $p(E)$ are isolated singularities of $g$.

**Step 3:** If $w_0 = p(z_0) \in p(E)$, then $g$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $w_0$: indeed, if $B\ni z_0$ is any open ball around $z_0$, then $V = p(B) \ni w_0$ is an open neighborhood of $w_0$, and $g(V)=(g\circ p)(B)=f(B)$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Thus, each such $w_0$ is a removable singularity of $g$.

**Step 4:** We're almost done- by step 3, there's a holomorphic function $h:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $h=g$ on $\Omega - p(E)$ (formed by adding the values of the removable singularities).

However, I'm not sure how to show that $g=h$ on $p(E)$. It would suffice to show that $g$ is continuous on the points of $p(E)$.

---

Is my outline correct? If so, how can we justify steps 2,4?

Comment: If I remember, for an isolated critical point $z_0$ of a holomorphic function $p$, there is local biholomorphic maps $\phi$ sending $0$ to $z_0$ and $\psi$ sending $p(z_0)$ to $0$ such that $\psi \circ p \circ \phi (z)=z^k$ for some $k$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

So you're reduced to the case you mentioned. Look for "Local behavior of holomorphic mappings"